# Javascript: Different behavior with single-argument Array.map() depending on whether I use curly braces or not (aren't both forms allowed?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, functional-programming

I'm experimenting with Array.map() and got this little snippet, which does perform as intended:

```
let cities = ["Buenos Aires", "Santa Fe", "Mar del Plata", "Mar de las Pampas"];

function urlify(string) {
  return string.split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase();
}

function functionalUrl(elements)  {
  return elements.map( element => urlify(element) );
}

console.log(functionalUrl(cities));

// ['buenos-aires', 'santa-fe', 'mar-del-plata', 'mar-de-las-pampas' ]
```

However, if I replace

```
return elements.map( (element) => urlify(element) );
```

with

```
return elements.map( (element) => { urlify(element); } );
```

(i.e., add parentheses and curly braces) it returns

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

I don't understand such behavior, as the curly braces/parentheses form is supposed to be "correct", and taking them away (I thought?) is just allowed in the specific case of a single-argument function...
What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Beware: if you are using curly braces, you need to put `return` inside, otherwise, it will return void, which is undefined as you can see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
elements.map( (element) => { urlify(element); } );
```

When you do the above code, you are creating the function body (assuming there are more lines of code to be included) and it expects the 'return' keyword, but if you are returning a single value (the result of one single computation), in your case

```
elements.map( (element) => urlify(element) );
```

then you don't have to specify the return keyword.

So the correct code for the second scenario using braces will be

```
elements.map( (element) => {return urlify(element)} );
```

The first one is a shorthand syntax not using the *return* keyword, also if you just have only one parameter you don't have to wrap the parameter inside the parenthesis.
So the more concise way should be

```
elements.map( element => urlify(element) );
```